# Why isn't this hole's context normalizing?

Tags: functional-programming, idris

On the following program:

```
module Bytes

import Data.Fin

%default total

Byte : Type
Byte = Fin 256

fromNat : Nat -> Byte
fromNat n = maybe FZ (\x=>x) (natToFin n 256)

toNat : Byte -> Nat
toNat FZ     = Z
toNat (FS b) = S (toNat b)

prop : (b : Byte) -> fromNat (toNat b) = b
prop FZ     = ?prop_rhs_1
prop (FS x) = ?prop_rhs_2
```

The hole `?prop_rhs_1` is not normalizing correctly. Idris says its context is:

```
--------------------------------------
prop_rhs_1 : maybe (Delay FZ) (Delay (\x => x)) (natToFin _ 256) = FZ
```

Notice it is displaying `(natToFin _ 256)` instead of `(natToFin Z 256)`, which should normalize to `Just FZ`.

Comment: It works with qualified names: `Bytes.fromNat (Bytes.toNat b) = b`

Comment: @AntonTrunov oh, right! Thanks.